# rock paper scissors lizrd spock game issue?

Tags: python

When I run my program my inputs do not print at all so I cannot enter my choice for the game.(Python)
There are no syntax error or anything from what I can see but I still cannot input which moves I want to enter.
I have defined player1 and player2 and have issued the correct parameters but nothing seems to be printing or being able to be input

```
while 1 == 1:
    print("\n1.ROCK 2.PAPER 3.SCISSORS 4.LIZARD 5.SPOCK 6.EXIT")
    player1 = int(input("\nEnter Player1's move (1-6): "))
    if player1 == 6:
        print("Player1 has left the game")
        break
    player2 = int(input("Enter Player2's move (1-6)"))
    if player2 == 6:
        print("Player2 has left the game")
        break
        move = ("ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS", "LIZARD", "SPOCK")
        victor = winner(player1, player2)
        if victor == 1:
            print(move[player1-1], "beats ", move[player2-1], ": PLAYER1 WON")
        elif victor == 2:
            print(move[player2-1], "beats", move[player1-1], ": PLAYER2 WON")
        else:
            print("Same moves! :", move[player1-1], "and ", move[player2-1])
            break
```

Comment: "*my inputs do not print at all*" Are you sure? Can't reproduce using [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@esqew/ConventionalSpringgreenKernelmode#main.py); voting to close.

Comment: Indentation -- I don't think you meant to have everything after the second `break` under the `if player2 == 6"`.

Comment: There are several issues with your code, starting with indentation. Also, winner is not defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, a part of your code is after the `break` for player 2, which means it doesn't run.

Remove one indent for this section:

```
        move = ("ROCK", "PAPER", "SCISSORS", "LIZARD", "SPOCK")
        victor = winner(player1, player2)
        if victor == 1:
            print(move[player1-1], "beats ", move[player2-1], ": PLAYER1 WON")
        elif victor == 2:
            print(move[player2-1], "beats", move[player1-1], ": PLAYER2 WON")
        else:
            print("Same moves! :", move[player1-1], "and ", move[player2-1])
            break
```